# github webcam caputure does not work

Tags: java, github, driver, webcam, capture

i'm using this api to get pictures from a webcam but i got this error

[click to see the error](http://s23.postimg.org/86rvh2bcb/error.png)

and this is the code. I start a thread in the formWindowOpen method and at the very bottom of the code there is the runnable class that takes the images.
thanks!!!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.abdulrahman.VideoSender;

/**
 *
 * @author abdulrahman
 */

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.*;



public class vidSender extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form vidSender
     */
    public vidSender() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 410, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
            Thread thread = new Thread(new camera());
            thread.start();
    }                                 

    private void setIco(BufferedImage img){
        ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(img);
        jLabel1.setIcon(ico);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vidSender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vidSender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vidSender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vidSender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new vidSender().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

public class camera implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
           try{
               Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
               webcam.open();
               while(true){
                   BufferedImage img = webcam.getImage();
                   setIco(img);
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           }
        }

}


}
```